# Verify all character sequences exist in a string (Python 2+)

Tags: python, regex

So to verify a string is a subset of another, with python, you can either use the `set/frozensets` class and the `issubset` method - only works for single characters, or you can use a regular expression, which would basically be multiple lookahead assertions from the start of the line. I want to use the regex option.

Without doing it the way below (using iterating through the strings and manually making lookahead assertions which may make a huge string given the big data I will be working with, is there another way to construct this lookahead in a more concise/straight-forward manner? The other item is that I will not be working with single characters only. So the number of lookahead assertions required could get really large.

```
import re

userInput = raw_input()
listOfChars = 'asdfgei'

myRegexString = ''
for i in listOfChars:
    myRegexString = myRegexString+'(?=.*'+i+')'
    myRegexCompiled = re.compile(myRegexString)
if myRegexCompiled.(userInput):
    print True
```

Comment: And what's wrong with using `set` operations?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge (and please correct me if i'm wrong) sets are slower, and sets will only work on single characters, will not work on verifying character sequences

Comment: Your title of verifying that all characters in a subset exist in a string seems substantively different from this reference to "character sequences." What do you actually want to do?

Comment: The latter, sorry for the confusion. Updated the topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to verify that all character sequences in a collection are present in a given string, use `all()` with a generator expression:

```
answer = all(word in string for word in bag)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Any idea how this compares with the regex solution when scaled?

Comment: This answer's better than mine, but perhaps use different variable names for clarity, or providing examples of what `word`, `string`, and `bag` might be.

Comment: @engineer14 This will also be O(M*N), where M is the number of elements in the set under test and N is the number of elements to test. You're avoiding the regex overhead (and possible worse-order behavior depending on how you write your regex)

Answer (score 0):

So let's say you have two strings -- `userInput`, which might be very large, and `listOfChars`, which is relatively small. You want to check whether each element of `listOfChars` exists in `userInput`, without converting `userInput` into a `set`.

There's no need to use regexes for this -- it'll be faster to just do it this way:

```
userInput = raw_input()
listOfChars = 'asdfgei'

def containsSubset(large, small):
   for element in set(small): # Convert to a set to remove dupes
       if not large.contains(element):
           return False
   return True

return containsSubset(userInput, listOfChars)
```

This will be O(M * N), where M is the size of `userInput` and N is the size of `listOfChars`.